# Want this simple query to loop

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want this query to loop, but add this question after getting the results, "Would you like to search for another column?"

```
ACCEPT column_name CHAR 
PROMPT 'Please insert column name' 
SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name IN ('&column_name');
```

If the user types in 'no' program ends with "Have a nice day". If user types in 'yes', the program starts over again requesting the user to input another column name.

I know it's simple. I mainly work in SQL Server, but Oracle is new to me

Comment: Sorry , here is the query....

Comment: ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please insert column name'
SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE column_name IN ('&column_name');

Comment: Holy smoky bones and coke!!! That was fast!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Don't forget to accept/up vote answers that help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with 2 SQL script files like this:

1) File myscript.sql:

```
ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please insert column name: '

SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE column_name IN ('&column_name');

-- Ask the user if the want to search again
ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Would you like to search for another column? '

-- Use a SELECT statement to look at their response and set variable "script" as appropriate
COLUMN script new_value script

-- Stop this select's results being displayed (in SQL Plus)
SET TERM OFF

SELECT CASE LOWER('&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'myscript' ELSE 'stop' END AS script
FROM DUAL;

-- Switch terminal output back on
SET TERM ON

-- Run whichever script the user chose i.e. "myscript.sql" if they said "yes", "stop.sql" if they said "no".
@&script.
```

2) File stop.sql:

```
-- This script just says "Have a nice day" then ends.
PROMPT Have a nice day
```

Depending on whether the user responds 'yes' or 'no', the script either runs itself again (loops) or runs the stop.sql script, which just says "Have a nice day".

Comment: What is the "@&script" for?

Comment: Where and what do I insert to stop sql if user responded "yes"?

Comment: The "@&script." command runs whichever script is selected in the preceding SELECT statement - either "myscript" or "stop".

Comment: If you create both scripts from my answer and run "@myscript" in SQL Plus you will see that it works as requested - every time the user responds "yes" it runs again, but when the user answers "no" it stops.

Comment: Im sorry I didn't inform you. I'm using Oracle Developer 12c. If you could please, can you include all lines of code. Adding comments would be AWESOME (I learn quicker with them)

Comment: I just wanted to copy and paste everything and run it

Comment: You have to create 2 files, you can't just paste it all in to SQL Developer.  But once you have that you can open and run "myscript.sql" in SQL Developer, press the Run Script button and it works.  There are no missing lines of code in my answer, it is complete and working code.  I can however add comments.

Comment: Ok I did what you said. Once I run it, it asks for a column name. I put in a column name, in the script output window it says "old:SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name" and it immediately asks for another column name. I insert a different name and it shows in the results the column is in two tables, then below it shows 11 rows selected and below that "old:SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name". It asks if I want to search for another column and I input "no". It shows some of the lines of code and a requestor pops up asking for value of script. I put in stop and it runs stop.sql then stops

Comment: Also "new_value" script has a red line under it. What should that be renamed to?