# Search for a column in a DB

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I received [help from a very great person (@TonyAndrews) yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34136540/146325) concerning this query...

```
ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please insert column name' 

SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name IN ('&column_name'); 

ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Would you like to search for another column? '

SELECT CASE LOWER('&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'table_search' ELSE 'stop' END AS script
FROM DUAL;

SET TERM ON

@&script.
```

I have two scripts created (`table_search` & `stop`). It just is not running right. He has given me the right info, I'm just to dumb to figure it out.

Im using Oracle Developer and running the script using the run script button. When I run it, it immediately comes up "Would you like to search for another column". In the script output window it shows "old:SELECT DISTINCT owner, table name" I type in "yes'" and in the script output window it appears to show the results of the initial search request. It does show the requestor window asking to input another column

Comment: "it's not running right". You **really** need to supply more info than that. Does it turn your monitor off? Make funny noises? Please explain in detail what it's doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have not qualified "not running right" with any information we can use to accurately diagnose your problem. If you do that then someone could help out.

In the meantime, looking at your script, it seems that if someone enters the column name in lowercase then your search will not find it as the Oracle data dictionary holds values in uppercase by default. Therefore, you should wrap your `('&column_name')` in an `UPPER`.

Also, you should probably trim any whitespace from the input just in case someone copies and pastes some by mistake.

Finally, you are using `IN` rather than `=`, is this deliberate? If you are searching for a column and offering the option to search again afterwards, I'd assume you would only search for one column at a time like this:

```
ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please insert column name' 

SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name = TRIM(UPPER('&column_name'));
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** I've been and looked at @Tony_Andrews answer and it seems pretty comprehensive to me. Have you created the two separate files "myscript.sql" and "stop.sql"?

Have you also stored those files in the default directory your SQL*Plus or SQL Developer installation is looking in when it is trying to run them?

Tony's answer is good, please describe in detail what issue you are having with it.

**EDIT2:** OK, following on from the information you have supplied, it seems that your initial variable is already set try adding `UNDEFINE column_name response` to your myscript.sql file before the `ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT ...` line. I would also add some `SET` commands to reduce the output to the screen to just what you want.

Your `myscript.sql` file should look like this (Note I have also added a double "@" when running the `stop.sql` as I am assuming it is in the same directory as the `myscript.sql` file):

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF

UNDEFINE column_name response

ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please insert column name' 

SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name = TRIM(UPPER('&column_name')); 

ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Would you like to search for another column? '

SELECT CASE LOWER('&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'table_search' ELSE 'stop' END AS script
FROM DUAL;

SET TERM ON

@@&script.

SET ECHO ON
SET VERIFY ON
```

This works for me.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok. Im using Oracle Developer and running the script using the run script button. When I run it, it immediately comes up "Would you like to search for another column". In the script output window it shows "old:SELECT DISTINCT owner, table name" I type in "yes'" and in the script output window it appears to show the results of the initial search request. It does show the requestor window asking to input another column.

Comment: I will post this in the original question for you.